# Azure, Databases and Uploading Documents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to figure out how add some functionality to an Azure/DB site an don't know where to start.

I have a table in my database called Equipment which contains Manufacture and Model Names of different types of equipment. I also have a table of Assets with a column that links (via a foreign key) to the equipment table. Both of these tables have ID fields.

What I would like to do is allow the user to be able to upload one or more documents against any item of equipment. As there can be more that one document for any equipment record I was planning on creating another table, also with a foreign key to the equipment table, containing some simple information about the doc and a link to the doc itself.

The end game being that in the detail view (MVC) of an Asset there will be a list of documents for the equipment type of that Asset.

I know how to do the last bit (document list) but I have no idea how to store and access docs in Azure, allow users to upload them and create a record in the docs table for each one.

I am guessing that I would add a link to the detail view of the equipment but that's as far as I have got.

sorry for the Epic but any tops or advice would be welcome.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score 2):

Use [blog storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) to store the uploaded documents for equipment.

Uploading a document into blob storage will result in the document being stored and accessible via a URI for example:
http://yourname.blob.core.windows.net/Equipment/EquipmentDoc01.docx

Store the URIs in your new table with the EquipmentID so that you can select all documents for that piece of equipment. List the documents and build the URI for users to select by appending the root blog storage URI.

Storing the relative URIs i.e. "/Equipment/EquipmentDoc01.docx" in your database table will enable you to move your blob storage around so you will have to append your database blob URIs with some config value i.e: http://yourname.blob.core.windows.net + DocumentBlobURI

New "Document" table will contain 3 columns

- DocumentID int KEY
- EquipmentID int FORIEGN KEY
- DocumentBlobURI i.e. /Equipment/EquipmentDoc01.docx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will have a play and report back my success :-)